# NavigationStack Limit

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I haven't found anything about this topic surprisingly. Is there a limit for the NavigationStack or can I push as many pages on it as I want? My feeling tells me that it will of course negatively affect the performance, but is there a general guideline or recommendation? For my application, I would need to place about 25 pages on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit to the number of pages you can place on the stack. It's simply an IEnumerable. The more pages that are there though the more memory your app will use. You should avoid avoid storing a large number of pages in there. Why do you need to store so many pages? if this is a direct navigation "shortcut" then you should check out Xamarin's [Shell Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation)

Comment: Basically the user needs to be guided through a series of processes and he has to complete them in order. The user should always be able to go to back but can never skip a page without successfully completing the most current one. Thanks, I will check it out!

Comment: @TomelSafadi I also don't find the limitation of navigationstack, about [improving  Xamarin.forms  performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance), also suggesting to use sell application.